# How to write unit tests for Angular component with @Input bindings?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, data-binding, jasmine

I can't imagine this is difficult, but I'm not finding documentation anywhere on how to write simple unit tests with Jasmine for a component with @Input bindings.

I have a basic component like this:

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'action-button',
  templateUrl: './action-button.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./action-button.component.scss'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
})
export class ActionButtonComponent {

  @Input('tableId') tableId!: string;
  @Input('actions') actions!: any;
  @Input('dataSource') dataSource!: any;

  constructor() { }

}
```

And this is the template, action-button.component.html:

```
<button mat-flat-button
    id="{{ tableId }}-create-button"
    *ngIf="!dataSource.selection.hasValue()"
    color="primary"
    class="green-gradient-button"
    (click)="actions.create.action()">
  <mat-icon>add</mat-icon>
  <span>{{ actions.create.text || 'CREATE' }}</span>
</button>
<button mat-flat-button
    *ngIf="dataSource.selection.selected.length === 1"
    class="gray-button"
    (click)="actions.edit.action(dataSource.selection.selected[0].id)">
  <span>{{ actions.edit.text || 'EDIT' }}</span>
</button>
<button mat-flat-button
    *ngIf="dataSource.selection.hasValue()"
    class="gray-button margin-left-10px"
    id="{{ tableId }}-delete-button"
    (click)="actions.delete.action(dataSource.selection.selected)">
  <span>{{ actions.delete.text || 'DELETE' }}</span>
</button>
```

I'm just going with the boilerplate spec file that Angular CLI generates.
I'm on Angular 11.
My tests are failing with errors like:

```
Chrome 90.0.4430.212 (Mac OS 10.15.7) ActionButtonComponent should have Actions FAILED
        TypeError: Cannot read property 'selection' of undefined
            at ActionButtonComponent_Template (ng:///ActionButtonComponent.js:83:50)
```

I've written hundreds of tests of other components and service, so I can't imagine this is hard. Just no able to find on SO what it is that I need to do here, just to mock out the component bindings.

Comment: Can you please post `action-button.component.html`?

Comment: Just added it above.

Comment: You haven't initialized dataSource

Comment: `dataSource` is initialized in the parent prior to being bound to this component.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply assign your `input` values before the first `fixture.detectChanges()` as shown [here](https://angular.io/guide/testing-components-scenarios#test-dashboardherocomponent-stand-alone). Notice how they do `comp.hero = ..` where `hero` is an `@Input()`.

To have full control of `@Input()` changes, you will have to create a dummy component and house your component inside of this dummy component and change the inputs from this dummy component. Check out testing with host component (dummy component) [here](https://angular.io/guide/testing-components-scenarios#component-inside-a-test-host).